# Make a div and a input width to be 100% of the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Consider a parent `<div>` which is `position:relative; width:100%`. It contains a  `<div>` and a `<input>`. I want them to have together a `100%` width.

The `<div>` ideally should be fixed (it's a custom button) and the `<input>` should fill the rest of the width (think about window resizing).

Is it possible doing it without involving JS code?

Also, it's not a "must-have" but I wish to support as for as I can with IE7+.

**CODE:**

```
<div id="parent" style="position:relative; width:100%">
  <div id="button">Click</div>
  <input type="text" id="txt_input" />
</div>
```

**CLARIFICATION:**
I am able to use javascript of course. If there isn't an elegant solution, then JS it is. Let me know please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without requiring extra HTML elements. For modern browsers, use flexbox. Here's a great list of browser support for flexbox http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox.

```css
#parent {
    display:flex;
}
#button {
  width:100px;
  background:red;
}
#txt_input {
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" style="position:relative; width:100%">
  <div id="button">Click</div>
  <input type="text" id="txt_input" />
</div>
```

And for older browser support, you can use table layout instead:

```css
#parent {
  display:table;
}
#button {
  background:red;
  display:table-cell;
  width:100px;
}
#txt_input {
  display:table-cell;
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" style="position:relative; width:100%">
  <div id="button">Click</div>
  <input type="text" id="txt_input" />
</div>
```

Comment: How is the support for display: flex for older browsers?

Comment: @DanielCheng I also added details of browser version support

Answer (score 3):

In this case, box-sizing: border-box comes in handy.
Let's assume the width of your button is 150px.

```html
<div id="parent" style="position:relative; width:100%; padding-left: 150px; box-sizing: border-box;">
    <div id="button" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 150px">
        Click
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="txt_input" style="width: 100%" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but the input doesn't fill the div's width.

Comment: @DanielCheng We have similar names and the same Chinese surname 張. :D

Answer (score 1):

This is the minimum I needed to make the `child` `input` element the same size as the `parent`:

```css
.parent {
position: relative;
}

.child {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input type="text" class="child" />
</div>
```